# Send 2 or more Raw Body Parameters Post Request with Postman

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, postman, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 API Method:

```
[HttpPost("api/days")]
GetDays([FromBody] DateTime startTime, [FromBody]DateTime endTime)
{

}
```

And I tried to send a Post request with Postman, but there is a problem, the parameters always have default values.

Here is my Post request looks like:

[image]

Result: Not Worked; Both parameters in API method get the default values.

If I change my API params to:

```
[HttpPost("api/days")]
GetDays([FromBody] Inputparam param)
{

}

public class Inputparam
{
    public DateTime startTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime endTime { get; set; }
}
```

That's worked perfectly!

But I wanna to send parameters directly and not inside wrapper object.

So, I came back with first API method and then I tried:

[image]

Result: Not Worked; Both parameters in API method get the default values.

And This one:

[image]

Result: Not Worked perfectly; Just first parameter (startTime) set it and second parameter still have default value.

And This one:

[image]

Result: Not Worked; Both parameters in API method get the default values.

I also tried `[FromForm]` instead of `[FromBody]` in API, nothings changed.

If I don't use `[FromBody]` in api and send the request via `x-www-form-urlencoded` that's worked perfectly.

But I need send a raw body with JSon.

How could I sent 2 different parameters as a raw body json?

Any idea?
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that it's just one `[FromBody]` [is allowed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody) in API, and that makes sense. So probably the answer is: There is no way to have 2 or more parameters with `[FromBody]` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

[FromUri] can do the Job.For your reference [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

```
public class DateTimes
{
public datetime startdate { get; set; } 
public datetime enddate { get; set; }
}

GetDays([FromBody] DateTimes _date)
{
  //Controller action
}
```

URI:

```
api/values/?startdate=2018-06-01&endate=2018-07-01
```

Comment: It's not Post By Raw Body